# Undefined symbol with g++

Tags: c++, unix, g++, java-native-interface

I have implemented the tutorial example of boost for the asio library, but with seperation through a header file:

[server.cpp](http://pastebin.com/DiT5v653)

[server.h](http://pastebin.com/5Z65HjEJ)

I build both files with another .cpp file in the following way:

```
g++ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include -L/usr/local/lib -fPIC  -lboost_system -shared -o libagent.so agent.cpp server.cpp
```

When using the shared library I have compiled, I get:

```
java: symbol lookup error: ./libagent.so: undefined symbol: _ZN14tcp_connection6socketEv
```

What seems to be the cause for this error? ldd -d gives me no dependency misses.

Comment: you can put your actual code here on this site.  It's a lot more useful that way.

Comment: did you set an LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: @SB: yes @Tim: ok, I thought it would be too much code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually linking to the boost::asio library, therefore the shared object doesn't know where to find the symbol that is being used in your class.

assuming the library is called boost_asio, you need to add:

```
-lboost_asio
```

to the link line.

... scratch that, completely wrong.

You're missing the implementation of the tcp_connection::socket - that's where the error comes from.

perhaps the line:

```
tcp::socket& socket();
```

in the .h file needs to read:

```
tcp::socket& socket() { return socket_; }
```

Comment: I cannot find this library, nor is it named this way.

Comment: sorry, I think it's called 'boost_serialization'

Comment: There are several dependencies: boost_thread, boost_serialization, etc. adding them all does not change the error

Comment: I used already the asio library, but with the code 1:1 from the tutorial. The error evolves since I use seperate files for header and source

Answer (score 1):

The most likely guess is that `./libagent.so` was compiled with a different compiler/settings/environment and the name mangling doesn't exactly match.